# IntelliJ IDEA shows redundant errors that do not exist

Tags: intellij-idea

I have problems with IntelliJ IDEA that appears after some time application is running. It finds errors in code which do not exist and marks them red. For example it tells me that one of arguments must be String instead of... String. The project of course builds ok.

Mostly there are few imaginary errors at time and I have to restart IDE to force it to behave normally.

What should I do to get rid off these problems?

And if it is relevant, I'm developing an Android application.

(IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1 Community Edition #IC-107.322)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-71782) is resolved in [IDEA 10.5.2](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+10.5+EAP).